# Retrieve a cookie value by startsWith

Tags: javascript

I've a cookie which is created for specific person, I would like to retrieve it on other page, but I am not sure which personId it will be it can be 1,2,3 etc. How could I retrieve the value for this cookie?

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie("PersonId" + personId);
```

Comment: Are you expecting multiple users to be using your site from the **same** pc and browser?

Comment: Yes it has a user accounts so the personId is taken from specific selected account. I.e. I can choose account with username 'Thomas' and his id is 2 so I would like to set a cookie with his id as above and as value object that holds 'Thomas'

Comment: @LeeTaylor a person can have multiple registrations. Or you could have multiple people using one PC - office, library, homes.

Comment: @Sdf19 Just relying on a cookie on the client's machine is not a reliable route to go. Do you have a server/database to verify credentials?